# how to support skype instant messaging without implementing skype client?

Tags: skype, instant-messaging

I was wondering how IM+/IMO --multiprotocol web messengers would be able to support skype instant messaging without SC(Skype Client),even pidgin does support skype but SC has to be installed in case of pidgin.I am very curious about the imo web messenger.Do they establish connection using skype API(i dont know) or some other way... Any one who have idea/clue about how it can be done please let me know.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Have a look at the following issue:

[How does Skype works in imo.im?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017942/how-does-skype-works-in-imo-im-and-im-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, skype uses propriatery protocols, and there are some efforts of reversing them:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol

Comment: thanks for your reply,I already checked that,it overlays the skype protocol basics.It will be very difficult to reverse -engg the protocol.But still I think imo have some kinda method to support skype.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It is now possible to connect through “Skype for Web”, allowing you to just use your browser to connect to the (clunky) web client.

Way better: [a recent plugin for Pidgin](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb) lets you use it directly through Pidgin, effectively adding true support for Skype in Pidgin.