# Log in and send messages with skype using node.js

Tags: node.js, skype

I can not find out how to connect to skype with node.js. If you have any information, please share it

Comment: You could say why are you downvoting or explain something...

Comment: You're being downvoted (I haven't downvoted you) because you do not say what have you tried so far? This is a 'Give me teh codez' question, which will get you several downvotes, many more to come I'm afraid. Try editing your question to include more information

Comment: @alexjamesbrown I can not try anything, because I don't need code example, I only need direction theoritically how can it be acomplished

Comment: Here is a Skype bot offering HTTP interface sending messages, can be invoked from Javascript too: https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot

Comment: Here is unofficial skype api https://www.npmjs.com/package/skyweb that uses Skype (HTTP) protocol that is used in web.skype.com

Comment: why was this flagged down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to communicate with Skype in that way.

A skypekit was requested by another user
http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Feature-Requests/SkypeKit-for-NodeJS/idi-p/8648

In much the same way you can't send iMessages from a non iOS device, you can't send Skype messages from anything other than Skype.

Comment: Not via any public api. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017942/how-does-skype-works-in-imo-im-and-im-services

Comment: Enlightenment :): 
Here is unofficial skype api npmjs.com/package/skyweb that uses Skype (HTTP) protocol that is used in web.skype.com